# SQL Equation => Image?

Tags: sql, latex, mathml

I'd like to go from this

COMPUTEDCOL1 = COL1 * COL1 / 7132

to this

[image]

Is there anything that can parse SQL and render it as above?

Thanks.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/mathtex/

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica would be able to do this in many cases.